# Error 'invalid data' while using node-v0.10.4 for websocket proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, websocket

I am using node-v0.10.4 to run web-sockets proxy to connect to particular kind of server. But I am getting the following error in my terminal after a connection is made via proxy using firefox browser(latest version). Error displayed in terminal :

```
net.js:595
throw new TypeError('invalid data');
      ^
TypeError: invalid data
at Socket.write (net.js:595:11)
at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/home/n-mol/Desktop/abs-master/wsproxy/wsproxy-tcp.js:69:10)
at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Receiver.self._receiver.onbinary (/home/n-mol/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:549:10)
at Receiver.opcodes.2.finish (/home/n-mol/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:448:14)
at Receiver.expectHandler (/home/n-mol/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:433:33)
at Receiver.add (/home/n-mol/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:93:24)
at Socket.firstHandler (/home/n-mol/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:524:22)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:710:14)
```

The following line of Javascript code is present at /home/n-mol/Desktop/abs-master/wsproxy/wsproxy-tcp.js:69:10

```
68. if (sock_ready) {
69.        sock.write(bytesView.buffer);
70.  } else ...
```

I guess there is some compatibility issue but I am not able to resolve it. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is `bytesView.buffer`?  If it's not a string or a Buffer (like, if it's `null`), you'll get that exception.

Comment: Variable bytesView is defined as following :
 var bytesView = new Uint8Array(data);
P.S. : Using a JS code not totally developed by me.

Comment: Well then `bytesView.buffer` is **not** a Node "Buffer" instance, and it's not a string either. That's what the error is telling you.  How you get it to be one or the other, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
if (sock_ready) {
  sock.write(new Buffer(bytesView));
} else
```

Looks like Node switched up the way it assembles a buffer in .10 vs .8 I just came across this problem too... about to submit a pull request to NDN-js ;)

Comment: Hey Ryan,
The issue was resolved as I was using code incompatible to node.js v0.10.x, the same as you pointed out. Thanks anyways :)
You are doing pretty cool stuff. All the best. 
Let me know if we can something together ;)